# using $.getJSON in a loop to append to global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a small script that takes an array of locations and geocodes them to add lat long to another object. I have it working so it geocodes and writes to the console flawlessly. How can I take that output and put it into a predefined variable outside of the function? I am not vary familiar with jquery and do not intend on using it anyplace else in the script.

Just started learning JavaScript this weekend so don't shoot me if Something else is messed up.

Thanks for any help!!

Also, I changed my Google API key so it isn't stolen.

```
      //test array of locations to geocode
var locationsToGeoCode = ["China: Shandong: Jinan",
    "China: Shandong: Jinan",
    "United States: Washington: La Conner",
    "United States: Texas: Dallas",
    "United States: California: Walnut"
    ];

//empty object to place geocoded places
var coordinates;

for (var i = 0; i < locationsToGeoCode.length; i += 1) {
  $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + locationsToGeoCode[i] + "&key=MIzaSyCywKsD_50EI9rheDLyqPOUdUzi6s6u-q8", function (geocodeResult) {
        console.log(geocodeResult);
        });
    }
```

Comment: `coordinates.push(geocodeResult)`?

Comment: @BradChristie that would work if he wanted an array, but from the question I think he wanted an object

Comment: I guess I wasn't taking "empty object" as literally as I should have been. ;-)

Comment: I don't think there's a clear preference expressed for array vs. object.  However, an array may be problematic when you have multiple async requests in-flight concurrently, with an object it's easier to avoid those kind sof problems by keying the responses properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code like such should work:

```
      //test array of locations to geocode
var locationsToGeoCode = ["China: Shandong: Jinan",
    "China: Shandong: Jinan",
    "United States: Washington: La Conner",
    "United States: Texas: Dallas",
    "United States: California: Walnut"
    ];

//empty object to place geocoded places
var coordinates = {};

function fetchGeoCode(location){
     $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + location + "&key=MIzaSyCywKsD_50EI9rheDLyqPOUdUzi6s6u-q8", function (geocodeResult) {
        coordinates[location] = geocodeResult;
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < locationsToGeoCode.length; i += 1) {
    fetchGeoCode(locationsToGeoCode[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 as this also averts potential issues with firing multiple async requests in rapid succession, such as having results returned in an arbitrary order.